# Laravel - phpunit fails the UPDATE method i dont know why

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

it's my first time writing test so I wrote one for the update method and I don't know what I did wrong
and if there's a better way of doing the test inform me please, thanks in advance

Routes

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'categories' , 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin'] , function () {
    Route::post('create', 'CategoryController@store')->name('category.store');
    Route::put('update/{category}', 'CategoryController@update')->name('category.update');
});
```

Here's my Controller

Controller

```php
public function update(Request $request , Category $category)
{
    $category->update($request->all());
}
```

Test

```php
/** @test */
public function a_category_can_be_updated()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $this->post(
        route('category.store'),
        [
            'name' => 'Food',
            'slug' => 'food-and-drinks',
        ],
    );

    $category = Category::first();
    $this->put(
        route('category.update', $category->id),
        [
            'name' => 'Food and',
        ],
    );
    // dd($category);

    $this->assertEquals('Food and', $category->name);
    $this->assertEquals('Food-and', $category->slug);
}
```

the Error comes from the Test

```
  • Tests\Feature\CategoriesTest > a category can be updated
  Failed asserting that two strings are equal.

  at F:\newProject\tests\Feature\CategoriesTest.php:66
     62▕             ],
     63▕         );
     64▕         // dd($category);
     65▕
  ➜  66▕         $this->assertEquals('Food and', $category->name);
     67▕         $this->assertEquals('Food-and', $category->slug);
     68▕     }
     69▕ }
     70▕

  1   F:\newProject\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:61
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
  --- Expected
  +++ Actual
  @@ @@
  -'Food and'
  +'Food'
```

Model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Category extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'categories';
    public $timestamps = true;

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = array('name', 'slug', 'parent_id');

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Post');
    }


    //slugging the Category-name
    public function setSlugAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($this->attributes['name']);
    }

    public function scopeParent()
    {
         return Category::whereNull('parent_id');
    }

}
```

let me know what is going on with the code, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by "IGP" you have to use `$category->fresh()` after performing the update. But assign that to your`$category` as follows: `$category = $category->fresh();`

Check the Laravel Documentation for details: [Eloquent ORM Refreshing Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#refreshing-models)

Comment: appreciate the time man it finally worked

Answer (score 1):

When doing this request,

```php
$this->put(
    route('category.update', $category->id),
    [
        'name' => 'Food and',
    ],
);
```

you're only updating the `Category`'s name with this request so after this, `$category->slug` will still be equal to `food`.

Nothing in your Model suggests the slug will be automatically updated.

Also, since the update was not done through the `$category` variable, you need to refresh its data after the put request with `$category->fresh();`

Comment: thanks for your time man, but I did write a set function for the slug in the Model already check it out

Comment: That function doesn't do what you think it does. It is called only when you manually set the slug, like in your first request and it doesn't care for the value itself. You could set `'slug' => ''` and you'd still get the same original slug.

Comment: i got what you mean but the first assertion is what fails first that means the name not there too not only the slug , and slug is nullable anyways , i updated the post with the error my bad

Comment: Oh, in the case the error is simpler. You just need to call `$category->fresh()` before the assertions. Since you updated the resource through the database via a request, the `$category` variable isn't aware of the changes and you need to tell it to refresh its data.

Comment: appreciate the time man , i will try it and give you the feed back thank you

Comment: unfortunately, it's the same problem, I don't  know why  I added the $category->fresh()  and before the assertions and the same

Comment: your answer is right but I have to assign it to the `$category` , thanks man I appreciate you